# In Objective C++ should I import or include C++ header files

Tags: import, include, objective-c++

Is there anything wrong with

```
#import "SomeCppHeaderFile.h"
```

in an objective C++ header? Or should I be including like this (is there any difference if the cpp header has the usual `#ifndef #define #endif` header gard macros)

```
#include "SomeCppHeaderFile.h"
```

Comment: I tend to use `#include` for C/C++ stuff and `#import` for Objective-C stuff, but I'm fairly sure either would do for either language (provided you don't `#include` twice files that don't have header guards) and you could settle for just one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with `#import "SomeCppHeaderFile.h"`. The `#import` directive does exist in the C/C++ preprocessors of GCC and Clang; the difference with `#include` is that it is designed to not include twice the same file in the same compilation unit.

This directive is not standard C, so if you expect to ship your libraries on other systems, be careful. As far as I know, it is supported only by GCC and Clang, and the guys at GCC don't like it much for this reason.